# Compiler Warning CS0067 : The event is never used

Tags: c#, events

I have an event that I am using, so I don't really understand what this warning really means. Can someone clarify?

```
public abstract class Actor<T> : Visual<T> where T : ActorDescription
{
    #region Events
    /// <summary>
    /// Event occurs when the actor is dead
    /// </summary>
    public event Action Dead;
    #endregion

/// <summary>
    /// Take damage if the actor hasn't taken damage within a time limit
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="damage">amount of damage</param>
    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        if (damage > 0 && Time.time > m_LastHitTimer + m_DamageHitDelay)
        {
            m_CurrentHealth -= damage;

            if (m_CurrentHealth <= 0)
            {
                m_CurrentHealth = 0;

                if (Dead != null)
                    Dead();
            }
            else
                StartCoroutine(TakeDamageOnSprite());

            m_LastHitTimer = Time.time;
        }
    }
```

In my other class, I register and unregister for the event:

```
        if (m_Player != null)
            m_Player.Dead += OnPlayerDead;

        if (m_Player != null)
            m_Player.Dead -= OnPlayerDead;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since the class `Actor<T>` is abstract, and no code inside `Actor<T>` raises the event, you can make the event abstract:

```
public abstract event Action Dead;
```

Then in subclass(es) which inherit from `Actor<T>`, you override the event:

```
public override event Action Dead;
```

If a subclass doesn't actually raise the event, then you can suppress the warning by giving the event empty `add` and `remove` methods (see [this blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/trevor/c-warning-cs0067-the-event-event-is-never-used)).

```
public override event Action Dead
{
    add { }
    remove { }
}
```

Comment: Ohhhh. That makes total sense!! Thank you!

Comment: I want to add that the warning is really about the "invisible" private backing field that exists for such an "auto-generated" event (called a field-like event). In the original code shown, the event was never raised, as you say, and no inheriting class could raise it (the backing field is private). So that was the error! If you write accessors `add` and `remove` by hand, there is no invisible backing field, and therefore no error. If you end up using this `abstract` approach, then **please** mark the implementation as `sealed`. That is, please use `public sealed override event Action Dead;`.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is that I am using Unity and Mono 2.6 and its still a bug. Therefore, I attempted to use the suggestion that Blorgbeard said, however; it worked for Visual Studio but not for the compiler.

So there are two solutions throwing #pragma warning disable around the event, or passing the generic type.

like so:

```
public abstract class Actor<T> : Visual<T> where T : ActorDescription
{
    #region Events
    /// <summary>
    /// Event occurs when the actor is dead
    /// </summary>
    public event Action<Actor<T>> Dead;
    #endregion

    ...

    private void SomeFunc()
    {
        if (Dead != null)
            Dead();
    }
}
```